# Статический и динамический массив (Си)

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, динамические-массивы

Пожалуйста, помогите с Си!

Статический и динамический массив (Си)

Напишите программу, которая:

• заполнить статический массив tabS из 100 элементов случайными числами от 1 до 100
(случайная функция),

• подсчитает, сколько из них из заданного диапазона <a,b>, а затем создаст массив
динамический соответствующего размера и заполнить его этими числами (функция
nowatabDyn с параметрами: указатель на статический массив tabS, его номер
n элементов, диапазоны a и b, указатель на количество элементов динамического массива m;
функция возвращает указатель на динамический массив).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int *losowe;
  int list[99];
  int n;
  int i;
  int a;
  int b;


  printf("количество чисел в массивe: ");
  scanf("%i", &n);

   srand(time(NULL));
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      
         losowe[i] = rand() % 100;
                        
         printf("%d ", losowe[i]);
      
      printf("\n");
   }
   printf("введите диапазон <a & b>:\n");
   scanf("%d/%d", &a, &b);
   for(int i=0; losowe[i]; ++i){
        if(a<=i && b>=i){
            printf("[%d]\n", losowe[i]);
           }
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите это правильное решение или я сделал не то что требовалось?

Comment: Не хотелось бы вас огорчать, но не будет это работать совсем. У вас есть указатель `losowe`, который указывает в неизвестное, случайное место в памяти. И вы туда записываете свои данные. Программа, скорее всего, мгновенно рухнет... Сначала память надо выделить (см. `malloc`).

Comment: ну сначала напишите этот статический массив `int tabS [ 100 ] ;` , а там глядишь и дело пойдёт.